# Conversion of decimal separator - DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, decimal, implicit-conversion, separator

I want to convert a double value column in DB2 SQL with ',' comma decimal separator to '.' dot decimal separator. My local settings are German. I can't change the DB settings since many applications are involved.

Eg : column value =0,81234  I want it to be displayed as 0.81234.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(COLUMNNAME AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS VARCHAR(25))
```

I tried converting it to decimal(8,2) first and then to varchar. This results in 0.81 (with '.' as expected). But I need all the numbers right of the decimal separator like 0.81234. So, I tried with decimal(7,6) which results in `SQL0413N OVERFLOW OCCURRED DURING NUMBER DATA TYPE CONVERSION error.`

Is there any other way to display the decimal separator as '.'?

Comment: `decimal(7,6)` means 7 digits in total, where 6 are decimals. E.g. 1.234567.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to higher digit value. Query runs fine. For certain values eg: 10 , it displays as 10.000000. Now I want for such values to have the trailing zeros trimmed and display only as 10. And when the value is 12.345000 then as 12.345

Comment: Can't you let the presentation layer handle this?

Comment: sadly, the results are exported and FTP'd directly to another layer where calculations are done.  Hence, want to implement a logic in SQL code itself.

Comment: Does that layer really bother about trailing decimal 0's?

Comment: I hope not, at the worst case, I would leave it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The separator is not actually stored in the DB for numeric columns.

Configure whatever tool you are using to look at the data to use your separator of choice.

Optionally you can run
`set option decmpt = *PERIOD;`

before running your select.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately, changing the tool settings to use the separator as period is not working. Hence trying to achieve through SQL.

Answer (score 0):

if you use JDBC you can modify it by adjusting your Connection string. Just add this

```
:decimalSeparator=1;
```

for point as decimal separator or 2 for comma as decimal separator